# Grails and OAuth

Tags: grails, oauth

I am using a REST JSON webservice which I want to secure. The service is secured with very basic Spring security and the session is stored on the server. So before the user can access the url "/api/resource" he/she needs to login first.

I want know how to:

- Only allow registered users to access my rest api
- Only allow registered clients with registered users to access my rest api(e.g. GWT, Android, iOS).  I dont want to let the users access my api if the client is not registered.

With a lot of googleing I saw the concept of **OAuth** which has the three way authentication method.

I am using grails in my project but I did not find any support for OAuth. Does anyone have experience using OAuth with grails? Is it easy to implement using Grails?

Thanks for help

Comment: Just wanted you to know that this exists but it doesn't fully solve your question.  Might get you headed the right way.  http://www.grails.org/plugin/oauth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've coded an OAuth library that is really simple and it's known to work with Groovy.

It's called scribe and you can give it a try here:

http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

### EDIT

If you need to implement an OAuth provider yourself, the only library I know is the [old oauth java lib](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/).

It's not very well documented but it has [some examples](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example/).

Comment: This looks like its a very nice library and easy to implement. I will definitely consider this if I need access to facebook and twitter etc. What I need is to implement a provider so that I have the same secure way to give access to my service like facebook or twitter

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin:

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-social-core

https://github.com/synergyj/grails-spring-social-core

They already have 2 implementations, Twitter and Facebook! Now you just have to create your own implementation!

Comment: Is this lib only for getting access to OAuth provider like Facebook and Twitter? My question was more like that I want to secure my server with OAuth like Facebook and Twitter did. So mainly I need the server part instead of the client part.

Answer (score 0):

Use the spring security oauth provider plugin. Creating an oauth provider is complex and you are in for a long haul of research and development but at the end you will have some experience that few have. Enjoy!