# Securing REST API in Grails and Spring Security

Tags: rest, grails

I have split my Grails app into two apps - a customer facing web app and a separate app that hosts a REST api. I am doing this because I'm building an iOS app to go with my web app. My app uses Spring Security and I want to secure the REST api. I've surprisingly found very little information on the proper way to do this. Should I implement oauth with Spring Security, thus making my API app an oauth provider?

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220359/grails-securing-rest-api-with-oauth2-0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095925/grails-and-oauth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951313/securing-grails-rest-service-for-use-with-mobile-applications

Comment: So basically a complete solution isn't currently available.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I just did this for another application. You have to tell spring security to behave differently when the REST URLS are accessed.

Add this to your `config.groovy`

Now you will have two parts of your application that are authenticated in the following manner

a) Anything with /api ( assuming thats how you have your REST set up) in the URL, gets the basic authentication

b) Everything else , goes through the login page.

```
// making the application more secured by intercepting all URLs 
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.basic.realmName = " REST API realm"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.securityConfigType = SecurityConfigType.InterceptUrlMap




//Exclude normal controllers from basic auth filter. Just the JSON API is included
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/api/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
'/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been working during the last weeks on a plugin that covers exactly what you want to do:

http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-rest

Have a look at it and let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.